# Deleting row elements except column1 and then shift cells up for the rest

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to delete all the row elements except the row element in column A and then shift cells up only for the deleted row using VBA coding. Right now I manually select a single row except the row element in column A and then delete using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and select shift cells up.

I have also tried this

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
```

but it deletes the whole row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify the range excluding that column e.g.

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1:D1").Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

You could also specify starting from B2, for example, and dynamically finding last column in same row:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
   .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(2, .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End With
```

To make that a little more easily amendable you can use Constants and you should have a test that lastColumn is > than START_COLUMN or you may delete the keep column.

```
Const ROW_OF_INTEREST As Long = 2
Const START_COLUMN As Long = 2
Dim lastColumn As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastColumn = .Cells(ROW_OF_INTEREST, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If lastColumn > START_COLUMN Then
        .Range(.Cells(ROW_OF_INTEREST, START_COLUMN), .Cells(ROW_OF_INTEREST, .Cells(ROW_OF_INTEREST, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thanks that really worked. Is there any way to reference the range if we do not have a fixed last element(D1 here) instead starting from B1 to row end?

Comment: The last version above dynamically finds the last column by coming from the right of the sheet and finding the last used column in the specified row.

Comment: That was really great. This one will serve the purpose for now. Thanks @Qharr

Comment: I cant upvote due to some reasons. Accepted the answer :)

Comment: I think you can upvote at like 15 points? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-are-15-reputation-points-required-to-upvote